# Missing property when trying to run a bash script in grails

Tags: bash, grails, gsp

I am trying to run a bash script through grails and i am stuck on a small error:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /FrameTest/loginKeys/index
No such property: loginKeysandFirstTest for class: frametest.LoginKeysController. Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: loginKeysandFirstTest for class: frametest.LoginKeysController
    at frametest.LoginKeysController.index(LoginKeysController.groovy:11)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

in my controller this is what i am coding:

```
class LoginKeysController {

    def index() { 
        "sh /Users/ironmantis7x/testfiles/mashery_login.sh".execute().text
        render (view: loginKeysandFirstTest)
    }
}
```

and my gsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>Demo Test Run Results</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i missing that is tripping this error in grails?
I am running ggts with grails 2.4.4.

Thanks.

ironmantis7x

Comment: I doubt this is the cause of your error, but I should point out that `sh` runs the POSIX shell, not bash.  There might be a symbolic link `sh -> bash` but when invoked as `sh` it behaves (mostly) as a standard shell and does not support any of the bash extensions.  If you want to run bash, then use `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with running `sh`. Take a closer look at the error:

> No such property: loginKeysandFirstTest for class:
>   frametest.LoginKeysController

No such property: **loginKeysandFirstTest** for class: **frametest.LoginKeysController**

The problem is with the line right *after* running `sh`:

```
render (view: loginKeysandFirstTest)
```

The *view* parameter expects the *name* of a view. So if the view is named *loginKeysandFirstTest*, then you can call render with that name as a `String`, like this:

```
render (view: 'loginKeysandFirstTest')
```